# EF Core : Foreign key returns null value : Repository Pattern

Tags: .net, api, .net-core

I've a `dotnet core web api` that's using `Repository Pattern` and `AutoMapper` to mapping resources to models ..,
Here is the `InMemoryDatabase` Implementation
[image: The Entity Product also implement HasData Attribute]
as shown below it's a `ProducRepository` That use EntityFramework`Include()`method to include category Data

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Products>>ListAsync(){
        return await _context.Products.Include(p=>p.Categories).ToListAsync();
    }
```

I implement category service for `HttpGet` and prepare the method that get data in `ProductController`here is the get method

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductResource>>ListAsync(){
        var products=await _ProductService.ListAsync();
        var resource = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Products>,IEnumerable<ProductResource>>(products);
        return resource;
    }
```

in `ProductResource` i passed `CategoryResource` in this way

```
 public class ProductResource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int QuantityInPackage { get; set; }
    public string UnitOfMeasurement { get; set; }
    public CategoryResource categoryResource { get; set; }
}
```

That means when i run the Product `Get Request`the `CategoryResource`must be executed beside `ProductResourse` but it returns `null` Just like this

[image]

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea here that the `product` and `ProductResource` just they are mapping for a `DescriptionAttribute` not for the include

```
 // Mapping Description Attribut
 CreateMap<Products,ProductResource>()
            .ForMember(src=>src.UnitOfMeasurement,
                
 opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.UnitOfMeasurement.ToDescriptionString()));

// Mapping Categories Table
        CreateMap<Products,ProductResource>()
            .ForMember(dto=>dto.Categories,
                conf=>conf.MapFrom(p=>p.Categories));
```